# mapping data with mongo query using custom key

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose

I have two collections - `orders`, `feedbacks`

Both have a key `reference_no` which does the mapping between them. I need to something like sql join between these two collections.

Before mongo I was doing it in plain javascript using map after getting data from two collections individually. But this breaks when I have to apply filter on one table.

Is there any way I can do it using mongo?

mongo version on production: 3.0.7

possible solution : I add reference of `orders` -> `_id` to feedbacks, but its not possible to do it now.

Comment: You can use $lookup on Mongo version 3.2. Refer this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I am using 3.0.7. Is there any other way out? In mongoose?

Comment: Lots of options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350495/how-do-i-perform-the-sql-join-equivalent-in-mongodb